# How to operate OSM-Carto in an Offline Mode

Tags: openstreetmap

I have run this OSM-Carto (https://github.com/gravitystorm/openstreetmap-carto) in Online mode.
In this OSM-Carto the tiles are using online "**https://...**" links to display maps in local host.
I have designed my tiles (covering specific area of the map) and the tiles Link is displayed from my file desired file-path like "**file:///...**" Where should the changes be placed by replacing the "https" link to  my "filepath" in this project files. I have already taken an overview on Kosmtik but still not figured it out.
Kindly guide me in running OSM-Carto in Offline mode.
Thanks in Advance

Comment: Please define "offline mode". A tile server doesn't need access to the Internet. You can access it locally.

Comment: Also, do you want to "generate tiles" offline or "access tiles generated previously" offline?  If the latter, then what you do will depend on what format you want the tiles in.  [Here](https://github.com/SomeoneElseOSM/SomeoneElse-style-legend/blob/master/rerender_legend.sh) is a small script that I use to generate tiles in a particular area for serving via a web server; something like that might work for you.

Comment: Actually I dont want to see the whole map in OSM-Carto. And also I don't want to pick the Tiles from HTTPS links. I have pinpointed the specific country and want to see that area Tiles on the local server. But where should I put that file path of that country in this OSM-Carto code.????

Comment: and in this OSM-Carto the tiles are picking from URLs like this (htps://a.tile.openstreetmap.org/${z}/${x}/${y}.png https://b.tile.openstreetmap.org/${z}/${x}/${y}.png https://c.tile.openstreetmap.org/${z}/${x}/${y}.png ).

Comment: I want to make the tiles to be picked/displayed from my specific file path in the local server.

Comment: @SomeoneElse Yes! I have already generated my tiles, now I want to access those Tiles in this OSM-Carto Project local server.
I am confused to how to proceed in this way..!

Answer (score 0):

Here's a very old [example](https://github.com/SomeoneElseOSM/OSMembedded/blob/master/Scripts/leaflet_embed.js#L16) using [Leaflet](http://leafletjs.com/).  If the tiles are on the local filesystem, you can reference them using local filesystem access.  How you do that in your case will likely depend the operating system that you're using and where you've put the files.  In the example the path without a file prefix is within the same package; the ones prefixed with "file://" are accessible via the local filesystem.  Actual filesystem paths will vary; the example was for Blackberry QNX.

Comment: Can I apply this example in **Ubuntu** Environment ?

Comment: Yes - use "file://" and an appropriate path.

Comment: In the Leaflet.js 
i have put certain changes by replacing https to file like this. Is it correct:

`var openStreetMap = L.tileLayer('file:///home/OSM_Project Folder/openstreetmap-carto/Pk/ur/tiles/{z}/{x}/{y}.png', { minZoom: 13, maxZoom: 13 });`

Comment: Is there a map tile at, for example "/home/OSM_Project Folder/openstreetmap-carto/Pk/ur/tiles/0/0/0.png"?  There should be a .png file there and if you view it in an image viewer it should look a bit like https://tile.openstreetmap.org/default/0/0/0.png does in a web browser.

Comment: The only other thing that I might try changing is to not have a "space" in the path - you've got "Project Folder" with a space in it.

Comment: Yes in this folder there is a .png file and it looks like my captured map.

Comment: Can u tell me n this whole profile where should i apply changes to run this project in Offline Mode ( for my offline tiles generated)

Comment: Sorry, I don't understand the question.  You're talking about "this project", but I have no idea what that is.  Could you perhaps add a few more details to the original question to explain what it is that you're actually trying to do?

Comment: Details Updated!

Comment: You still haven't said what "this project" is.  Presumably you've obtained a Leaflet example from somewhere, changed it, and now it doesn't work.  Unfortunately only you know what you've changed so you're going to have to be the one to debug it.

Comment: "this project" means the current github OSM-Carto which I am using and trying to change it to Ofline and the details I already mentioned

Comment: No changes are needed to OSM-Carto itself to use it offline.  If you want to generate tiles for offline use using python you may need to manually edit the fonts used by the style to match the ones that you have installed on your OS.

Comment: I have used Maperative Tool to generate Tiles of a specific Area. Now I want to put that map file path in the **OSM-Carto github** code. The path has been placed but that map area is not being displayed...! Not whats the issue...?